# Hover over display related text for simple form association field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am using Rails and simple form. I have a collection that I am displaying with an association field. For each item in the collection, I want to display a hover over title of an attribute belonging to that item, namely `description`.

Here is my association:

```
<%= f.association :user_roles, collection: @roles, as: :check_boxes, label_method: :name, label: false %>
```

I want to display a hover over text of the description of each role. In my head something like the following should be doable:

```
<%= f.association :user_roles, collection: @roles, wrapper_html: {title: UserRole.where(id: this_current_items_id).first.description}, as: :check_boxes, label_method: :name, label: false %>
```

or:

```
<%= f.association :user_roles, collection: @roles, wrapper_html: {title: :description}, as: :check_boxes, label_method: :name, label: false %>
```

Neither of these work obviously but in my head a solution like this should be easy. I guess the guys at simple form never thought of this situation.

However, is this possible to do? Or, how can I get the ID of the current item so that I am displaying that items description on hover over?

PS: What I need is a simple form `hover_method`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add other attributes to each item in your collection like so:

```
<%= f.association :user_roles, collection: @roles.map { |r| [r.name, r.id, { title: r.description, "data-toggle": "hover" }] }, as: :check_boxes, label: false %>
```

Comment: Fantastic, I made some changes to your answer, though, I will verify it worked when I get home but so far so good, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I tested it, and it works. I edited my answer again - just to show how you can also put data attributes and regular HTML attributes like "title" as you have done.